# Validation of args passed to generic mutation in base resolver

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-graphql

#### Current behavior

- I have a base class and some derived classes
- There is a BaseResolver, which is inherited by the resolvers of the derived classes
- Inside the BaseResolver, there is a create mutation
- This create mutation takes in different arguments depending on the derived class
- There is a create DTO for the base class, the create DTO of the derived classes inherit from this class
- I pass the create DTO class of the derived class to the BaseResolver while inheriting it in the derived resolvers

Base resolver:

```
export function BaseResolver<
  T extends Type<BaseClass>,
  createClassDto extends Type<CreateBaseClassDto>,
>(classRef: T, createClassArgsDtoRef: createClassDto): any
```

Derived resolver:

```
@Resolver((of) => DerivedXClass)
export class DerivedXResolver extends BaseResolver(
  DerivedXClass,
  CreateDerivedXDto,
)
```

- I specify the type of the arguments as follows:

```
 async createMutation(
      @Args({ type: () => createClassArgsDtoRef })
      args: Type<CreateBaseClassDto>,
    )
```

- The arguments are not being validated at all

#### Minimum reproduction code

It has the steps to reproduce and the expected behaviour.

https://github.com/snigdha920/nestjs-validation-args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's probably a cleaner way to do this, but something hacky would look like

```js
    @Mutation(() => Boolean, { name: `create${classRef.name}` })
    async createMutation(
      @Args({ type: () => createClassArgsDtoRef })
      args: // @ts-ignore
      createClassArgsDtoRef,
    ) {
      console.log('class is ', classRef.name);
      console.log('args captured are ', args);
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Typescript essentially doesn't understand that what you pass here is in fact a class reference and it should be used as a type. There's probably a better way to set this, maybe even the use of a custom parameter decorator, but this works for now and satisfies general type usage to the best of my knowledge